# Why does the `index` parameter in the `each` method behave differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, each

Why does the `index` parameter in the `each` method behave differently in this scenario?

http://jsfiddle.net/4h4fy/1/

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    $('li').text(index);// This prints only 2s 
    console.log(index);// This prints 0, 1, 2 
});
```

How I can I get it so that 0, 1, 2 prints along side the `<li>` tags?

Comment: you actually have nested loops

Comment: Ironically, the answer to your question is almost identical to the example used on the JQuery `.each()` page: http://api.jquery.com/each/   :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(index);
});
```

Simply passing your `$('li')` within a `.each()` won't capture the context correctly. You need to use `$(this)` instead.

And the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/G7ZnM/1/

Answer (score 4):

Each time you go through the loop, your setting the text for *every* `li` to current index. So in the end they will all be set to whatever the last index was.

Try this instead:

```
$('li').each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).text(index); // This prints 0, 1, 2 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 'this' to refer to current 'li' :

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(index);// This prints 0,1,2
    console.log(index);// This prints 0, 1, 2 
});
```